# Collision works except for when coming from right side

Tags: collision-detection, libgdx, collision-resolution

I am trying to make a bomberman clone. I'm having problems with the collision on the walls that is not on the sides of the map (see image). When I come from the right (going left), the red square (player) goes through the wall but when I come from other sides (up, left, down) the collision works well and the player does not go through. The collision on the side walls works well also even when I come from the right and going left.
[image]

I am using Tiled and LibGDX and here is the code:

```
private void checkCollision(float delta) {
    //player.getVelocity().scl(delta);
    Vector2 position = player.getPosition();

    // just to see if it overlaps because this is the location of the 
    // rectangle when getTiles is called when player moves left as shown in the image
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(128, 128, 64, 64);  
    if(player.getRectangle().overlaps(rect)) {
        System.err.println("overlap"); 
    }

    if(player.isMovingRight()) {
        Array<Rectangle> tiles = getTiles((int)(position.x/TILE_SIZE + 1), (int)(position.y/TILE_SIZE - 1), 
                (int)(position.x/TILE_SIZE + 1), (int)(position.y/TILE_SIZE + 1));
        for (Rectangle tile : tiles) {

            if(player.getRectangle().overlaps(tile)) {
                System.out.println("overlap right");
                player.setPosition(tile.x - player.getWidth() , player.getPosition().y);
            }
        }
    }
    if(player.isMovingLeft()) {
        Array<Rectangle> tiles = getTiles((int)(position.x/TILE_SIZE - 1), (int)(position.y/TILE_SIZE - 1), 
                (int)(position.x/TILE_SIZE - 1),  (int)(position.y/TILE_SIZE + 1));
        for (Rectangle tile : tiles) {

            if(player.getRectangle().overlaps(tile)) {
                System.out.println("overlap left"); // this doesn't show
                player.setPosition(tile.x + tile.width, player.getPosition().y);
            }
        }
    }

    if(player.isMovingUp()) {
        Array<Rectangle> tiles = getTiles((int)(position.x/TILE_SIZE - 1), (int)(position.y/TILE_SIZE - 1), 
                (int)(position.x/TILE_SIZE + 1), (int)(position.y/TILE_SIZE));
        for (Rectangle tile : tiles) {

            if(player.getRectangle().overlaps(tile)) {
                System.out.println("overlap up");
                player.setPosition(player.getPosition().x, tile.y + tile.height);
            }
        }
    }
    if(player.isMovingDown()) {
        Array<Rectangle> tiles = getTiles((int)(position.x/TILE_SIZE - 1), (int)(position.y/TILE_SIZE + 1), 
                (int)(position.x/TILE_SIZE + 1), (int)(position.y/TILE_SIZE + 1));
        for (Rectangle tile : tiles) {

            if(player.getRectangle().overlaps(tile)) {
                System.out.println("overlap down");
                player.setPosition(player.getPosition().x, tile.y - player.getHeight());
            }
        }
    }

    //player.getVelocity().scl(1/delta);

}

private Array<Rectangle> getTiles(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY) {
    TiledMapTileLayer layer = (TiledMapTileLayer)level.getMap().getLayers().get(1);
    Array<Rectangle> rectangles = new Array<Rectangle>();
    for (int x = startX; x <= endX; x++) {
        for (int y = startY; y <= endY; y++) {
            Cell cell = layer.getCell(x, y);
            if(cell != null) {
                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x*TILE_SIZE, y*TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE);
                rectangles.add(rect);
            }
        }
    }
    return rectangles;
}
```

Comment: What does the `isMovingLeft` method look like? Also, why are you creating a new `playerRect` in each if-statement if the `player` already has a `getRectangle` method?

Comment: i don't know libGDX so tell me what is your Reference/Anchor/Pivot point when you are creating Player Rect? Means `(int)position.x` and   `(int)position.y` represents what point, center? or upper left corner?

Comment: @bordander sorry, I forgot to change it back to player.getRectangle().

Comment: @Hamza Hasan it's in the upper left

Comment: In `player.isMovingLeft()` check, try to change 3rd parameter of `getTiles` from `(int)(position.x/TILE_SIZE - 1)` to `(int)(position.x/TILE_SIZE + 1)`

Comment: @bornander isMovingLeft is just a getter of boolean

Comment: @Hamza Hasan what the hell, so that was the problem. Now it worked! Thank you! But why do you think that was the problem? The 1st and 3rd parameter was just startX and endX (them being equal) which is just to the left side of the player. Changing it to +1 includes the tile to the right of the player.

Comment: @Zik Rounding errors probably got the `position.x/TILE_SIZE` to be one left of the player, then when you subtracted `1` you went a whole more tile to the left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The glitch is in your `isMovingLeft` method. You are giving in `getTiles` same `X` value in `start` and `end`. That is why it is creating no geometrical area.

So change do change in `player.isMovingLeft()` check, 3rd parameter of `getTiles` from `(int)(position.x/TILE_SIZE - 1)` to `(int)(position.x/TILE_SIZE + 1)`.

By this it will create an area of your tile size.

Comment: But in the getTiles method, my for loop condition is <= so it should still make at least 1 area

Comment: @Zik what about your boundaries? are they also considered as tiles?

Comment: Do you mean the walls on the sides? Yes, and they are part of the collision checking

Comment: And with `-1` it is colliding with walls? if so then don't you thing that your once called for loop considering that wall?

Comment: Yes, the player collides with the walls. Anyway, after this problem was solved, I have another problem and I might put it into another question.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if there is a collision.
2. Find the direction of the collision.
3. Move the player to the opposite side.

Forget about checking which direction the player is moving.
get rid of `if(player.isMovingLeft())` and others.

After finding collision,  compare the positions of the tile and the player to find the direction of the collision. Then move player in the other direction. If you are using `speed*timeElapsed` to move the player normally, use it again when moving in the other direction from the collision.

In order to find the direction of the collision:

```
if (player.width/2 + tile.width/2 < Math.abs(player.x - tile.x)) {  
    // collsion  from left or right
    if (player.x > tile.x) {
        player.setPosition(tile.x + player.width/2 + tile.width/2, player.y)
    }
    else {
        player.setPosition(tile.x - player.width/2 - tile.width/2, player.y)
    }
}
```

You can use this to find if there is a collision too.

**NOTE:** Always move player in the opposite side or reposition the pleyer, don't block movement.